# Automatically updating the users location in a maps activity (Android)

Tags: java, android

So I wrote a class that will find the users location and find the distance between that and another point but I have a random number generator so when I call I use method I use in my activity (restarting the activity) the random number changes which I don't want to happen. If anyone would show me how to refresh the users location on the click of the button without restarting the whole activity it would be a great help

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    //These variable are initalized here as they need to be used in more than one methid
    private double currentLatitude; //lat of user
    private double currentLongitude; //long of user

    Random rand = new Random();
    int n = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;

    int score = 0;

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    //contains lat and lon of another place
    private void setUpMap() {


        if (n == 1) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeVillageApartmets, longitudeVillageApartments)).title("1"); //create marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker); // adding marker
        } else if (n == 2) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeSU, longitudeSU)).title("2"); //create marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker); // adding marker
        } else if (n == 3) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeArtsBuilding, longitudeArtsBuilding)).title("3"); //create marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker); // adding marker
        } else if (n == 4) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeJH, longitudeJH)).title("4"); //create marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker); // adding marker
        } else if (n == 5) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeForebell, longitudeForebell)).title("5"); //create marker
            mMap.addMarker(marker); // adding marker
        }
    }
    //contains your lat and lon
    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("You are here");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((latLng), 11.0F));
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        //Refresh button. Will reset the location of your flag
        //If the user clicks the button, the activity is finished and restarted
        Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View w){
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
 }
```

Note if there's a problem with the code I delete a lot of it so it's only brackets and stuff. I just posted all this so you have an idea what's happening. I only want to refresh your location, not the entire activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one ? I did not test it.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
Marker marker;

private void setUpMap() {
  if(marker!= null)
    marker.remove();
  markerOptions = null;
  if (n == 1) {
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeVillageApartmets, longitudeVillageApartments)).title("1"); //create marker

  } else if (n == 2) {
        markerOptions =  new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeSU, longitudeSU)).title("2"); //create marker

  } else if (n == 3) {
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeArtsBuilding, longitudeArtsBuilding)).title("3"); //create marker

  } else if (n == 4) {
      markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeJH, longitudeJH)).title("4"); //create marker

  } else if (n == 5) {
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitudeForebell, longitudeForebell)).title("5"); //create marker

  }
 if(markerOptions!=null)
  marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions); // adding marker
}
```

And on your onclicklistener

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View w){
           n = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
           setUpMap();
        }
});
```

Or you can use marker.setPosition(LatLng); if your marker is not null